# div x inside mutilple divs cant expand its height specified in %?

Tags: css, html, height

i have a sidebar having many nested divs to place my rounded corrners.but when i tried to set the content's div height equal to 90% its not expanding.what is the issue.my html,body have 100% height.my div nest is some what like this.

```
<body>
<div class="main">                //it contains header n content div,its height is 90%
<div class="header"></div>        //its height is 10% of main div
<div class="content">             //its height is 90% of main div

<div class="vertical_navigation"> //its height is 99% of content div

<div><div><div><div>              //thses divs are for rounded corner image concept
<div> </div>                      //this div contains the data.now its height is 80% but its not expanding?h
                                  //i cant use min-height,its not working too.how to give height referenced to                                //vertical navi div??
</div></div></div></div>

</div>

</div>

</div>
<footer></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Try posting your *actual* HTML and CSS, rather than discussing it 'somewhat.' Also, welcome to Stackoverflow! =)

Comment: Max-height and min-height are not always guaranteed to work. The situation you describe should work in theory, so I frankly have no clue why it's not.

Comment: if you can understand my problem..no actual code is needed.i had posted very clearly my problem..it doesnt need actual code...only some logic is missing...

Comment: "//it contains header n content div,its height is 90% //its height is 10% of main div //its height is 90% of main div //its height is 99% of content div" - this is hard to understand. Please post your HTML/CSS :)

Comment: Oh, I see. There is code there, it's just not indented correctly. *fixes*. However, your CSS would still be useful.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered applying rounded corners with just css and not worrying about the ieretards not having them?

Answer (score 0):

When having so much nested div, it's good you consider the measurement in width and height of the DIV if the container div is lesser that the ones inside it, it won't stretch,because that way, the browser can't detect how far the div is meant to stretch. to resolve this use make proper use of CSS.